# Integrating Hyperterm in Webstorm or IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, hyperterm

I was trying to integrate Hyperterm inside the WebStorm. Even though I have specified the valid path. Then Hypeterm opens up in a new instance. Does anyone knows how to make that docked inside WebStorm.

URL: https://hyper.is/

Here is my settings.

[image]

And when I click on terminal in WebStorm it pops out as a separate instance

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. HyperTerm is a standalone application that provides its own terminal UI, replacing the built-in terminal UI of WebStorm. It's not possible for WebStorm to dock an external application inside its UI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It make sense.